# Representing inheritance from a templated class

Tags: templates, uml, class-diagram

I was wondering how I'd represent a template class inheriting from another template class in UML?

Something like this:

```
class non_templated {
   ...
};

template<typename x>
class templated_a {
    ...
};

template<typename y>
class templated_b
  : public templated_a<y>,
    public non_templated {
    ...
};
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo have class `templated_b` that inherits from `non_templated` and from `templated_a`. The template parameter of `templated_a` is the same as the one of `templated_b`. In this case I think that it is sufficient to draw both classes as having a parameter with the same name:

[image: Class diagram 1]

In my opinion it is obvious that `Y` is the same parameter, so I prefer to keep the diagram as clean as possible and not add additional notations.

But there are also different opinions. [This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/umlforum/ueN2xbZo2zk) question is from someone who is afraid that people might not find that obvious: `"how to know Y of templated_b is the same type than Y of templated_a?"`

If you have the same concerns, than you can use the UML template binding notation.

> "Template binding is shown as a dashed arrow decorated with the
>   keyword «bind» and binding information, with the hollow triangle
>   arrowhead, and directed from the bound element at the tail to the
>   template."

[Here](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/template.html#template-binding) you can read more about it.

Using this notation your diagram would look like this:

[image: Class diagram with template binding]

I don't like that, because it uses two different types of lines for inheritance and I think that most people wouldn't understand the template binding notation.

An alternative would be to add a `<<bind>>` stereotype and to the generalization line and name it as `<Y->X>`. This makes the generalization line resemble to the template binding notation. Something like:

[image]

Even though this is not formal notation for template binding I prefer it to the second diagram. And I prefer even better the first. I think it is the diagram most people would understand better. You could even include the binding parameters information in the stereotype: <Y>>`. It's up to you to select what is better understood by the people for which the diagram is drawn.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It certainly does help! I was thinking the same: that it'd be quite obvious to most. The form I went with initially was first binding template_a<...>, creating an intermediary step and then generalizing that to template_b. That added a ton of steps for more complex templates. I like your solution! Sometimes, I guess, strictly complying to the UML spec. can hinder understanding!

Comment: Also! What program did you use to generate the diagrams? I'm using Astah right now.

Comment: I am using Astah too!